# what's wrong with this spring mvc security config

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc

```
web.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>myweb</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:myweb-security.xml
                classpath:myweb-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>


        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>myweb</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>

the output：


----------



    2013-10-18 15:44:03 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    信息: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    警告: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myweb' did not find a matching property.
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    信息: Initialization processed in 1110 ms
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    信息: Starting service Catalina
    2013-10-18 15:44:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    信息: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
    2013-10-18 15:44:08 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    信息: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    2013-10-18 15:44:08 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    2013-10-18 15:44:08 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    信息: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    2013-10-18 15:44:08 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    信息: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 18 15:44:08 CST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    2013-10-18 15:44:08 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinidtionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    信息: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [myweb-security.xml]
    2013-10-18 15:44:09 org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion <clinit>
    信息: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.4.RELEASE
    2013-10-18 15:44:09 org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
    信息: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.4.RELEASE
    2013-10-18 15:44:09 org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthenticationConfigBuilder createLoginPageFilterIfNeeded
    信息: No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
    2013-10-18 15:44:09 org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
    信息: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2000]
    2013-10-18 15:44:09 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    信息: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [myweb-servlet.xml]
    2013-10-18 15:44:10 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    信息: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46c80e21: defining beans [org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,helloController,helloServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,sessionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    2013-10-18 15:44:10 org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
    信息: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@35d56bbe, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4e94a28e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3c40f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@73cb4cae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@28176ee6, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1a71d29a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@26b98a06, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5f14a3c6, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@440c4cee, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@38ec029, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@10e9c592]
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
    信息: Checking whether login URL '/spring_security_login' is accessible with your configuration
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.5.Final}
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    2013-10-18 15:44:11 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
    INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    2013-10-18 15:44:13 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    2013-10-18 15:44:13 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
    INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
    2013-10-18 15:44:13 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    信息: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5695 ms
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    信息: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myweb'
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    信息: FrameworkServlet 'myweb': initialization started
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    信息: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'myweb-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 18 15:44:14 CST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    信息: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    严重: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        ... 29 more
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    严重: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        ... 29 more
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    严重: Servlet /myweb threw load() exception
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    2013-10-18 15:44:14 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    信息: Server startup in 9878 ms
```

according the errors,
    it seems it want to create two application context.One is created by
            classpath:myweb-security.xml
            classpath:myweb-servlet.xml
    ,and another is by /WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml.
    what is wrong with web.xml?

Comment: FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml] ....is this file present in classpath

Comment: <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:myweb-security.xml
                classpath:myweb-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

Comment: i want to use xml file in classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContextLoaderListener` by default is loading a file called **applicationContext.xml** from the web application root (i.e. /WEB-INF). This can be overriden by specifing a `context-param` with the name **contextConfigLocation**. This however doesn't influence the `DispatcherServlet`

The `DispatcherServlet` by default tries to load a file called **[servlet-name]-servlet.xml**. This can be overriden by specifing an 'init-param' (for the servlet) with the name **contextConfigLocation**.

In your case the files are in the classpath and not in the WEB-INF root.

Another note in general the myweb-servlet.xml should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` and not the `ContextLoaderListener` also don't load the configuration twice as that will lead to bean duplication (and problably some nice other problems as no-transactions, memory issues etc.).

Comment: changed to:<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myweb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:myweb-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   classpath:myweb-security.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: now the server started without errors.but the security config does not works.seems there are two contexts created by DispatcherServlet and ContextLoaderListener

Comment: Correct. Both create a context, the `DispatcherServlet` uses the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` as a parent. As I mentioned your **myweb-servlet.xml** should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, let the `ContextLoaderListener` load the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use classpath, it is better to put WEB-INF.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/myweb-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```